# raspberrypiからphpへPOSTでセンサデータを送りたい

Tags: python, php, apache, raspberry-pi, xampp

PC上でラズパイから送ったセンサのデータをCSV形式で保存しようと考えているのですが、data.csvは作成されますがデータが書き込まれません
ちなみに渡しているデータはカンマ区切りのデータ（1,2,3.1,4.2,5.3のようなもの）です

ラズパイ側かphp側どちらに問題があるのかすらよくわかりません
めちゃくちゃな質問とは思いますがどなたか詳しい方いらっしゃいましたら助言お願いいたします．

データ送信部（raspberrypi）

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpio_seri = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=10)
    print(gpio_seri.portstr)
    time.sleep(3)
    while 1:
        gpio_seri.write('get')
        time.sleep(1)
        data = gpio_seri.readline()
        print(data)
        url = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/test1.php/"
        s = requests.session()
        r =  s.post(url, data)
```

データ受信部（php）

```
<?php

    $data1 = $_POST['data'];

    $filename = "data.csv";
    $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a');

    $line = implode($data1);

    fwrite($fp, $line . "\n");

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: データ受信部のPythonスクリプトでurlの最後が`test1.php/`となっていますが、末尾のスラッシュは余計な気がします（これが直接の原因かは分かりませんが…）。

Comment: まあ末尾スラッシュは問題ないでしょうねw この場合の問題はform-data形式でないpostを$_POSTで読もうとしてることです……

Comment: form-dataについて調べてみてもよくわからないのですが，python側のデータの送信方法を見直した方がいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 送信側受信側、いずれを変更するアプローチも取れますがこの目的なら受信側かな……（両方要修正ではあるなのですが）

Comment: とりあえずデータ送信側を`r =  s.post(url, data={'data': data})`とすると、どうなりますか?

Answer (score 1):

解決しました
下記のコードのように変更すると成功しました
コメント下さった方々本当にありがとうございます

コメントを参考に送信側を色々変更しました

加えて受信側の書き込みの部分はfwiteを用いずにcurrentに変更しました

送信側

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import serial
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gpio_seri = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=10)
    print(gpio_seri.portstr)
    time.sleep(3)
    while 1:
        gpio_seri.write('get')
        time.sleep(1)
        bio_data = gpio_seri.readline()
        print(bio_data)
        url = "http://192.168.0.103:8080/test1.php/"
        response = requests.post(url, data={'bio_csv': bio_data})
```

受信側

```
<?php
    $data1 = $_POST['bio_csv'];
    echo $data1;
  $file = 'test.csv';
  $current = file_get_contents($file);
  $current .= $data1;
  file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```